# Entity framework error in MVC5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've tried the following but it does not help

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012252/using-fuslogvw-exe-on-a-machine-with-no-visual-studio-installed
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.] System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while trying to run project:The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135925/error-while-trying-to-run-projectthe-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly)

Comment: @Kami-No its not!I already go over the post and the proposed solution was not helped my out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing some Nugget package...(from your error description ).

You can add the `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` from Nuget packages and then rebuild the project and then automatically add the `EntityFramework.SqlServer dll`.

Let me know if it helps.

Good luck!
Shimi